# Oracle: private et public synonyms

Tags: oracle

When executing statements that address objects without a schema qualifier, Oracle will first look for the object in the local schema, and only if it cannot be found will it look for a public synonym.

For instance i have created two (02) synonyms:

```
create public synonym emp for oe.employees;
create synonym emp for hr.employees;
```

I'm logged like HR and I executed the following statement.

```
select * from emp;
```

How refer to a public synonym if it has the same name like a private synonym?

Answer (score 2):

No, Oracle will select the local synonym before looking at for a public synonym during object resolution.  You cannot scope your object to skip this and only resolve to the public synonym.

[Object resolution docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general008.htm#ADMIN11561)

Comment: Ok But in my case i want to refer to the public synonym. How can i do it.

Comment: @Steve  you cannot

Comment: @Steve: But Gary Myers says, you can: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44233916/754550

Comment: @Gary Myers has given a workaround, but if you don't have access to modify the code that contains the reference you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot reference a synonym explicitly. Oracle interprets `emp` according to the fixed scope of the name resolution​ rules.

So you have two choices:

1. Hard code the schema name:

   `Select * from oe.employees;`
2. Create another private synonym:

   `Create synonym not_my_emp for oe.employees;`

Neither of these is ideal but the cause of the problem is the original decision to have a private synonym which overrides a public synonym.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select * from "PUBLIC".EMP
```

The owner of the synonym is PUBLIC, but that's a reserved word in various situations. The double quotation marks is a workaround.

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: It worked in a 12.1 environment. No idea about older versions, or 12c Container/Pluggable environments.

Comment: I tried it and obtained this message:
desc "PUBLIC".EMP
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object "OE"."ORDERS" does not exist

Comment: In the Oracle Database SQL Language Reference it is said: "Take care not to create a public synonym with the same name as an existing
schema. If you do so, then all PL/SQL units that use that name will be invalidated."